# CPU Speed reduce few hours later

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance

When I first start my laptop/windows 10, CPU Speed is around 1.85 GHz.
if I do something CPU bound task it increase to around 2.40 GHz. Then reduce  around 1.80  GHz as expected...

After few hours later.. (sometimes 1 hour later) No particular situation, CPU Speed reduce to 0.96 GHz and doesn't increase anymore... So my laptop starts to work slowly...

It is not a heat issue.
Power plan set to High performance.

Is there anyway to detect the reason ?

First hours CPU Speed seems normal...

[image: First hours CPU Speed seems normal...]

Lower to 0.96 GHz and doesn't increase anymore:

[image: Lower to 0.96 GHz and doesn't increase anymore]

Comment: "It is not a heat issue" -- I wouldn't be so sure. Laptops are far from always designed to run for hours on end. Let's see some CPU temperature data.

Comment: When I restart my laptop it start with normal speed values. I think heat doesn't go away with restart. This is why I do not think it is heat issue. But of course never say never... Current temperature is around 57C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out driver problem.
Lots of people had same problem after upgrading Win 10.
I had to downgrade Intel DPTF (Dynamic Platform Termal Framework) from 8.xxx to 6.xxx.

But now problem is my CPU speed doesn't fall blow 2.5 (which higher then average speed)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your BIOS and disable Enhanced Intel SpeedStep® Technology. More information on it can be found at http://www.intel.com/cd/channel/reseller/asmo-na/eng/203838.htm

Hope this helps

Comment: I do not see the setting you wrote... I do not see CPU temperature in my bios either.. is there a advanced bios settings option or something ? My laptop is : asus ux32vd